# Custom keypoints tracking using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

What is the best way to train TensorFlow for custom keypoint tracking that can work on the web?
Right now I'm using [CenterNet MobileNetV2 FPN Keypoints 512x512](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20210210/centernet_mobilenetv2fpn_512x512_coco17_kpts.tar.gz) to train, but the outcome is not good enough keypoints confidence is significantly less approx 30%, but the bounding box is fine. So is there any way I can improve the model confidence for keypoints?

Config which im using:
steps 25000
epoch 12
learning rate 0.01
train dataset 1280
test dataset 319

Im trying to train a ml model using tensorflow that can track custom kwypoints but my tain model is not working as im expecting

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.